# How to inherit from twisted.logger.Logger?

Tags: logging, twisted, logfile

I have a tcp server with Twisted, and each client has a log file. So I inherit from twisted.logger.Logger.

```
from twisted.logger import Logger, textFileLogObserver
from twisted.python.logfile import LogFile

class LALogger(Logger):
    logger_root_path = os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'log')

    def __init__(self, log_folder, log_file_name):
        super().__init__(namespace='')
        logger_path = os.path.join(self.logger_root_path, log_folder)
        self.log_file = LogFile(log_file_name + '.log', logger_path,
                            rotateLength=1000000, maxRotatedFiles=5)
        self.observer = textFileLogObserver(
            self.log_file, timeFormat='[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]')
```

When the log file came large than 1000000, it should rotate. But sometimes cann't rename the log file.
I guess I should close the log file before rotate. How should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't subclass `Logger`.  If you want a `Logger` with a particular observer, just write a function:

```
def my_logger():
    observer = textFileLogObserver(...)
    la_logger = Logger(observer=observer)
    return la_logger
```

If you want to change the log file rotation behavior, you need to change the behavior of `LogFile` somehow - because that's what actually writes the log file.

Fortunately, `LogFile` is just an object with a `write` method.So you can create your own object which implements `write` any way you like (including whatever special rotation logic you need) and use that instead.

However, `LogFile` already closes the file before it rotates it.  So, investigate further regarding the cause of whatever rotation-related error you're encountering so that you can fix the correct problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your suggestion.